# Adding Unicode decorators to text in Pages

Tags: pages, unicode

Is it possible to add a copied (via `Cmd+C`), for example, vector arrow to  a letter in Pages? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the character viewer by selecting Special Characters from the Edit menu. It doesn't support copying characters, but you can add characters by dragging them to text views.